# Turning on PC PSU with current or bridging PS_ON and COM/GND?

Tags: power-supply, switches, sata, hdd

I really hope title is specific enough.

What I am trying to achieve is that using a [SATA Extension Cable](https://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA9UP5305097) to PS4 you can plug in a 15mm 2.5" Laptop Drive or 3.5" Desktop Drive and the issue is that the internal SATA connection provides no 12v for 3.5" HDDs so 3.5" HDDs that require the 12V will not spin up due to inadequate power.
I have a 430W PSU lying around and have it set up so that it provides SATA power of 12V and 5V DC to the HDD and just have the SATA III data connected to PS4. But for this I ALWAYS need to make sure I turn on the HDD power before the PS4 or the PS4 will spend a minute trying to boot and then warn of "Cannot Connect to Storage".
Is there a way to connect the 5V from PS4 to PS_ON so that when the PS4 boots and attempts to power on the internal drive it switches on the PSU via the PS_ON + GND bridge causing the HDD to be adequately powered and everything flows nicely. During PS4 shutdown, the last thing to lose power is the HDD, thus turning off the PSU.

Is this possible?

Comment: Always power the HDDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a master PSU control a slave PSU is pretty easy.

Grab yourself a 2N3904 or similar transistor and a 22K resistor. Hook the emitter of the transistor to ground, the collector to PS_ON of the slave PSU, and the base via the resistor to the 5V line of the master PSU.

The only potential problem is whether the PSU and HDD start up fast enough to satisfy the PS4.

Comment: Wow thanks for this, you make it sounds insanely simple.The PS4 is not some super fast boot-drive-is-SSD machine, it takes a fair bit to get past the logo screen so if your tip works, I would gather that this is perfectly fine. Now just need to figure out a place to get the transistor and resistor, already have all the soldering goodies. Here in Canada, those parts stores a dime a dozen.

Comment: Any idea if either of these resistors makes a difference?  
SG73G1JTTD2202D 0.33W  
SG73G2BTTD2202D 0.5W

Comment: Electrically either of those resistors is fine, but unless you are making a PCB for this you will probablly find the construction easier with a resistor that has leads.

Comment: would FMP200JR-52-22K be better choice if I do not plan to PCB this. I will most likely hex shape breadboard this together and wrap everything in heat-shrink.

Comment: It will work fine but the power rating it serious overkill which means it will be bulky and a pain to heatshrink over. The power dissipated in the resistor is about a milliwatt, so even the lowest power rating resistors should be fine, something like  SFR2500002202FR500

Comment: Grabbed a 0.25W res by accident, still good?

Comment: yeah, absoloutely fine.

Comment: great, even got the 24pin header so I can make an adapter. going to put it together tonight or morning. I'll follow this:  `Grab yourself a 2N3904 or similar transistor and a 22K resistor. Hook the emitter of the transistor to ground, the collector to PS_ON of the slave PSU, and the base via the resistor to the 5V line of the master PSU.`

Comment: Peter, I know its been awhile, I have only now gotten the pieces together and the time to try this out. Does it matter which ground I use? PS4 or PSU ?

Comment: Took the risk and attached the Emitt. to GND of the PSU -- AND IT WORKED!  for all about 2mins before things shut off, I checked the back and the Base of the Transistor, Pin, snapped off. I think I may have bent it too much plus the added strain from the PSU THICK 24pin tugging the opposite direction, I would blame my soldering (3rd-4th time using an iron) but it was the entire pin that snapped off. guess I should breadboard it or, hot-glue or see if I can find a three pin pcb. Thanks a lot Peter, it worked! no delays.

Comment: [photo](https://imgur.com/a/sJtZErt)

Comment: The grounds of the two PSUs need to be connected together, they are probablly connected already through the power cords and through the devices they power, but you should still connect them explicitly.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I do not get alerted about these comments. Are you saying that my current setup (Emitter to GND of External PSU) is bad? there is the GND from the SATA connection of the PS4, but that is not connected to anything. To be precises, the ePSU and PS4 are connected to different Power-bars, but to the  same wall-socket (Socket 1 - PS4's powerbar, Socket 2 - ePSU's powerbar, as there are other devices near the TV)

Comment: The grounds must be connected. It's probablly working now because they are connected via the grounds in the data cable and on the hard drive's PCB but you shouldn't rely on that, you should connect them explicitly.

Comment: Can it be any ground? like PS4 SATA connection GND to PSU SATA Power connector's GND ? I have a male sata connector from a previous purchase, I could just solder an adapter, like I did for the Trans. to PS4 5v. ( so I can easily swap things out if the PSU dies or I get a smaller one, did not want any permanent connections). So I would connect PS4 Sata GND to male connector and just plug the Sata power connector from the PSU in... ?